# Javascript converting from string to instance name

Tags: javascript, class, methods, method-call

I have a string representing the name of a tool in a screen painting application (examples: 'pencil', 'marker', 'line', 'rect').  For each tool, I have defined a class to perform that tool's functions (e.g. `PencilHandler`) and created an instance of it (e.g. `pencilHandler = new PencilHandler()`).  Currently, I use a long switch statement to go from the name of the tool (a string) to the corresponding instance (an object) (e.g. `switch(tool) { case 'pencil': return pencilHandler; ...}`) and then call a method of the returned instance (e.g. `pencilHandler.mousedown(event)`).

It would be neater if I could dynamically construct the instance name from the tool name rather than  using the switch statement, but I haven't been able to find out how to do this.  For instance, `tool + 'Handler'[mousedown](event)` doesn't work (gives a TypeError).

Comment: You want to store your instances in a `Map` by their name.

Answer (score 1):

collect them in one object and call by key name

```
const classesCollection = { PencilHandler, ErazerHandler, BrushHandler }
const requiredClass = classesCollection[tool + 'Handler]
```